# Tablesorter not working for newly added items

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter, x-editable

In the page below:
http://homecoders.co.nf/test.html

We're using TableSorter, QuickSearch, X-Editable.

TableSorter and QuickSearch works properly, except for newly added item.
For instance, try clicking "Enable Edit", add an item, then "Disable Edit"

The new Item (whatever you typed), will be searchable, but will NOT be sorted by the TableSorter.

FYI, JSFiddle doesn't work with this particular page so I decided to put the page in a hosting instead of it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where to add this as I've never used X-Editable before, but maybe within the success callback?

Basically, you need to update the table, if it's a small table, then just trigger an update:

```
$('table').trigger('update');
```

on large tables, it would be more efficient to just update the edited cell

```
// update the table, so the tablesorter plugin can update its value
// this = table cell (td) to update
// resort = flag prevent (if false only) automatic resort
// if resort is undefined, or with any other value, a resort will occur
// callback = callback function
$("table").trigger("updateCell", [this, resort, callback]);
```

Comment: I tried to put the trigger, but it doesn't seem to work. I have decided to ditch using x-editable. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Try out the [content editable widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-editable.html), maybe it'll suit your needs?

Comment: Didn't know you have this handy plugin! It will definitely suit my need. Thank you so much!!